# UIKit Dynamics in iOS Control Center

Tags: ios, uikit, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior

I am simply trying to mimic the animation behaviour of iOS Control Center.

I am trying to implement UIKit Dynamics in to an UI element.  It's a panel sitting on the bottom half of the screen and I want it to slide up with a pan gesture and snap with bounce just like iOS Control Center.  Also want it to snap back with urgency just like on Control Center.

I successfully attached a UIPanGesterRecognizer and initiated these:

- UIGravityBehavior
- UICollisionBehavior
- UIPushBehavior
- UIAttachmentBehavior
- UISnapBehavior

After experimenting with all those, I have not, yet, successfully grabbed the behavior of the Control Center.

Does Apple talk about how they implemented it somewhere? In a sample code or WWDC video?

Comment: Actually I suspect that it's a `usingSpringWithDamping:` view animation. Apple does talk in one of the videos about how to pan partway and then pick up the gesture and turn it seamlessly into an animation the rest of the way.

Comment: I know they use UISnapBehavior when it slides up.  However, that doesn't give the 'urgency' on the way back down.

Comment: "I know they use UISnapBehavior when it slides up" How do you know? Do you understand that that's quite different from what I'm talking about?

Comment: YES.  Because what you are talking about is adding spring dampening to UIView animations.  If you inspect the control center closely, you can see the spring animation is variant.

Comment: Okay, cool. Well, you clearly have strong opinions of your own about how this is being done, and other people's opinions are not of interest to you. So it's a bit hard to understand what the question is. Obviously Apple is not revealing the details. So it is up to you to reverse-engineer it as best you can.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be edgy with you. I spent days trying to replicate it.  So far, when it snaps up, I am pretty sure that they use UISnapbehavior with spring dampening. I'm really unsure how they are doing sliding down action.

Comment: @gizmodo did u figure it out?